# Why can't I update the value of a function argument in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, arguments

I have this code:

```
 fun main() {
    // count digits of given number while
    println("please enter number program counts its digits")
    val n = readLine()?.toInt()!!
    println(countDigit(n))
    println("$n consists of ${countDigit(n)} digit(s)")

}

fun countDigit(i:Int):Int{
    var counter = 0
    var number = i
    while (number>0){
        number/=10
        counter++
    }
    return counter
}
```

The thing I don't get is why I have to do `var number = i`. When I use `i` itself it is not working

```
fun countDigit(i:Int):Int{
    var counter = 0
    while (i>0){
        i/=10
        counter++
    }
    return counter
}
```

Comment: `it is not working` what does it mean? Code throws exception or produces wrong result or...?

Comment: function parameters are immutable, hence you can't change their value.

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko when I hover over 'i/=10' it says: Val cannot be reassigned! 
'@Alex.T answered to my question, I appreciate it!
I want to be sure whether this is 'var number = i' right or proper way.

Comment: That's the right way to do it. Use the parameter to initialize a new `var` if you need to modify it.